# Control Chromecast buffering at start

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

Is there a way to control the amount of buffering CC devices do before they start playback?

My sender apps sends real time audio flac and CC waits +10s before starting to play. I've built a customer receiver and tried to change the autoPauseDuration and autoResumeDuration but it does not seem to matter. I assume it's only used when an underflow event happens, but not at startup.

I realize that forcing a start with low buffering level might endup in underflow, but that's a "risk" that is much better than always waiting such a long time before playback starts. And if it happens, the autoPause/Resume hysteresis would allow a larger re-buffering to take place then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, it turned to be a problem with the way to send audio to the default receiver. I was streaming flac, and as it is a streamable format, I did not include any header (you might be able to start anywhere in the stream, it's just a matter of finding the synchro). But the flac decoder in the CC does not like that and was talking 10+ second to start. As soon as I've added a STREAMINFO header, problem went away

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Media Player Library, take a look at player.getBufferDuration. The docs cover more details about how you can customize the player behavior: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player#frequently-asked-questions

Comment: Thanks - I saw that but that just gives me an information wrt the amount buffered, it does not let me force the player to play. It seems to me that MPL still decides whenever it wants to play. There is also this function playWhenHaveEnoughData, but how can I know/set what "enough" means?

Comment: You could try to override the MPL functions to see if you can change the default player behavior.